# z-index + overflow:auto = bug?

Tags: html, css, overflow, z-index

I am making popups as `position:fixed` div and propogate through hierarchy `z-index` to ensure that this div is on top of everything. Everything fine, except one case when Chrome draw scroll over my popup, iOS safari clips my popop.

I made super small repro https://codepen.io/heavenmaster/pen/XWrQmZY
Note, position `absolute` and setting `z-index` is essential for me.

I desperately need a workaround.

```css
.scrollview {
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: solid gray 1px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.container {
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
  width: 1000px;
  height: 1000px;
}

.tooltip {
  z-index: 1;
  width: 250px;
  height: 50px;
  border: solid 1px gray;
  background: silver;
  position: fixed;
  left: 80px;
  top: 80px;
}
```

```html
<div class='scrollview'>
  <div class='container'>
    <div class='tooltip'>Tooltip</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: it seems to be a chrome bug, everything is fine on FIferox

Comment: @TemaniAfif unfortunately not only chrome,  and I desperately need a workaround.

Comment: a workaround is to remove z-index from `scrollview`

Comment: I know there is some bug with Chrome where the parent container also have to be `position:absolute` so it works correctly. Did you tried this?

Comment: can u try to create the "tooltip" div outside the "scrollview" div and make z-index:2 to "tooltip"?

Comment: @FahimKhan my goal is to have tooltips or any other popups in the element where it related

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok let's try this I hope its help:

```css
.scrollview1
{
  z-index: 1;
    position: absolute;
    margin: 100px;
    width: 250px;
    height: 200px;
}
.scrollview
{
  z-index: 1;
/*   position: absolute; */
/*   margin: 100px; */
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: solid gray 1px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.container{
  z-index: 1;
/*   position: absolute; */
  width: 1000px;
  height: 1000px;  
}

.tooltip{
  z-index: 1;
  width: 250px;
  height: 50px;
  border: solid 1px gray;
  background: silver;
  position: fixed;
  left: 80px;
  top: 80px;
}
```

```html
<div class='scrollview1'><div class='scrollview'>   
  <div class='container'>    
    <div class='tooltip'>Tooltip</div>    
  </div>  
  </div></div>
```

Comment: I am accepting this answer, because it works in this particular case, hope it helps someone (in my more complex case it was not enough - still buggy on iOS)